# How to display year-based Gmail labels in reverse chronological order?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I set up year-based labels in Gmail to archive old mails -- e.g. year 2001, year 2002, ... year 2013, year 2014, etc.

The problem is that Gmail displays the labels in the alphabetical order, which, in turn sorts these year-based labels in chronological order.

But as with anyone else, I need to look up recent emails more often than decade-old emails, which means that the label I need to reach most often will sit at the bottom of the year-based labels.

Would there be a clever way to display these year-based labels in reverse alphabetical order (i.e. reverse chronological order)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to reverse the sort but you still have a way to get them near the top.

When sorting alphabetically there is a trick to start a label with one or more underscores. This will put them  at the top of the list. You could start this years label with "__aYear2015" and last years label with "__bYear2014", the older years labels could either follow the pattern or drop the underscores.

Now what happens when the new year starts. If you right click on the label in the label list, you will see a bunch of commands. One of the commands is edit. The edit command allows you to change the label. Al messages with that label are automatically adjusted.